# Qt conflicting with GLee

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm adding OpenGL support to a game that is based on Qt 3 (office politics).  The basics (QGLWidget, etc) work fine.

To get to OpenGL extensions, I arbitrarily chose GLee (it compiled out of the box, GLew didn't).

GLee.h and qgl.h don't play nicely together. AFAICT, each must be included before the other.

I yanked the preprocessing checks [that make sure it's included first] out of GLee.h, inserted the preprocessing directives it uses before including the OpenGL headers, then included qgl.h first.  On linux, it boils down to:

```
    #define __glext_h_  /* prevent glext.h from being included  */
    #define __glxext_h_ /* prevent glxext.h from being included */
    #define GLX_GLXEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <qgl.h>
#include "GLee.h" // my hacked version
```

That builds (no idea whether my code will actually run yet...this question's pre-emptive [i.e. I'm procrastinating]), but it seems like a horrible kludge.  Googling has turned up a lot of people asking this basic question (though most of them haven't bothered figuring out the bogus compiler errors so they can see the root problem), but I haven't seen any actual answers.

Is there a better (more elegant, portable, robust, etc) way to do this?

Comment: This sounds suspicious. What makes you believe that each header must be included before the other? What are the errors you get?

Comment: GLee.h has precompiler checks so it must be included first (which is what I pulled out to get this hack to build). When I include the standard GLee.h first, I get errors from qevent.h (and sometimes qnamespace.h) about numeric constants and 'friend' used outside of class (along with others that imply a missing } somewhere). http://www.qtcentre.org/forum/f-general-programming-9/t-problems-with-q-object-and-subclassing-823.html has a good error list, but that fix didn't help me.

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your problem? Can you mark one as accepted then?

Answer (score 3):

This still isn't as clean as I'd like, but it at least builds and runs, without hacking GLee.h.

After everything else, #include qobject.h, GLee.h, and qgl.h (in that order).

So, the header file might look like

```
...blah...
...other #includes

#include <qobject.h>
#include "GLee.h"
#include <qgl.h>

class MyGlWidget : public QGLWidget
{
...
}
```

then the soure file would #include that file last.

Comment: What's wrong with that? Looks as good as you can hope for given the way Trolltech chose their identifier names... You might want to add a comment explaining the include order, but other than that it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (Very ugly, still, but so seem all solutions to be except using glew):

```
#include <GL/GLee.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#undef Status
#undef Bool
#undef CursorShape
#undef Unsorted
#undef None
#undef KeyPress
#undef KeyRelease
#undef FocusIn
#undef FocusOut
#undef FontChange
#undef GrayScale
#undef Expose
#undef Complex

...

#include <qgl.h>
```

Comment: Hi, just ran into this problem with GLee 5.5 and Qt5.1.1. I would add `#undef Expose` and `#undef Complex` to the list of problematic macros

Comment: Thanks, added them to the list

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your patch won't work, since it prevents necessary headers from being included. This can cause all sorts of weird problems.

(**Edit:** I no longer suspect that, after reading one of your comments - if all you pulled out of GLee.h were the checks and #error directives, things should work... Probably.)

As far as I can tell, the problem stems from Qt trying to define enumerations that conflict with X preprocessor macros. Specifically, CursorShape is defined by X.h to be 0, and then by qnamespace.h to be an enumeration, resulting in the rather unhelpful error message "error: expected identifier before numeric constant"

A cleaner way to do what you're trying to do is to include the files in this order, and with these macros undefined:

```
#include "qgl.h"
#undef __glext_h_
#undef __glxext_h_
#undef __gl_h_
#include "GLee.h"
```

This doesn't require patching GLee.h, but may yield unexpected results, depending on why GLee.h wants to be included first.

A better solution would be to include GLee.h and qgl.h in separate compilation units, but that may not be possible.

By the way, a good debugging strategy for this sort of problem is to pass -E to gcc - this will give you the preprocessed source, which you can examine to find the offending line. In this case, the enum name was replaced by a 0 constant, which made it clear that the name was being defined elsewhere. Grepping for the enum name under /usr/include revealed the offending header to be X.h. Well, to be fair, the offending pary here is Qt - developers should know better than to use X11 constants as identifiers in a cross platform framework.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use glew. it works just fine with QT.